# Rvest: Headlines returning empty list

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to replicate [this tutorial on rvest here](https://www.aggieerin.com/post/gathering-text-from-the-web/). However, at the start I'm already having issues. This is the code I'm using

```
library(rvest)
#Specifying the url for desired website to be scrapped
url <- 'https://www.nytimes.com/section/politics'

#Reading the HTML code from the website - headlines
webpage <- read_html(url)
headline_data <- html_nodes(webpage,'.story-link a, .story-body a')
```

My results when I look at `headline_data` return

```
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

But in the tutorial it returns a list of length 48

```
{xml_nodeset (48)}
```

Any reason for the discrepancy?

Comment: There are no elements with class `story-link` nor `story-body` at that page.

Comment: My guess would be that the webpage CSS has changed since the tutorial was written. You'll need to visit the webpage and inspect the elements to see what the nodes should be now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are no elements with the specified class you are searching for.

To begin, based on current tags you can get headlines with

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
url <- 'https://www.nytimes.com/section/politics'

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("h2.css-l2vidh a") %>%
  html_text()

#[1] "Trump’s Secrecy Fight Escalates as Judge Rules for Congress in Early Test"                    
#[2] "A Would-Be Trump Aide’s Demands: A Jet on Call, a Future Cabinet Post and More"               
#[3] "He’s One of the Biggest Backers of Trump’s Push to Protect American Steel. And He’s Canadian."
#[4] "Accountants Must Turn Over Trump’s Financial Records, Lower-Court Judge Rules"
```

and to get individual URL's of those headlines you could do

```
url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("h2.css-l2vidh a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  paste0("https://www.nytimes.com", .)

#[1] "https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/20/us/politics/mcgahn-trump-congress.html"                                                                   
#[2] "https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/20/us/politics/kris-kobach-trump.html"                                                                       
#[3] "https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/20/us/politics/hes-one-of-the-biggest-backers-of-trumps-push-to-protect-american-steel-and-hes-canadian.html"
#[4] "https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/20/us/politics/trump-financial-records.html"
```